# Discover if a variable is a number

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Is there a Way To compare nan with a variable?I need this To understand if a variable is a number or Not without using javascript's functions.

Comment: Without using Javascript functions…?! What's the point of that?

Comment: Without using parseint or something like that?

Comment: Where is your code, where is your attempt, what is your desired output?

Comment: javascript has isNaN() which returns true or false...

Comment: I haven't ideas so i don't know what To write

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why would you want to avoid calling a function for that, but here is a quick hack:

```
var myNumber = NaN;
typeof myNumber === "number" && myNumber + "" !== "NaN"
```

this way you get true if its a `number` and not `NaN`, if its only a number, it will return true if its nan or a non number, it will return false/

again, it is recommended to use the `isNaN` function

Comment: An other question:Can i  put a returned value in a variable?For example if i return nan,Can i put It in a variable?

Comment: so `"1"` is a number?

Comment: ofcource you can, quick example: `var a = number` if number is NaN, then a is NaN..

Comment: @StephanBijzitter true, i updated the condition to check for number aswell.

Comment: `myNumber + "" !== "NaN"` -> `myNumber !== myNumber`

Comment: @StephanBijzitter your suggestion is invalid because NaN does not strictly equal itself. `NaN === NaN // false`

Comment: yeah that was my point, but i seemed to have read your `!==` as `===` which indeed makes my comment useless :D

Answer (score 0):

You can always test if a value is NaN by checking it for equality to itself:

```js
var foo = NaN;
console.log(foo !== foo); // true 

var bar = 4;
console.log(bar !== bar); // false
```

There is a [note for this in the ECMAScript specs](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number).

Based on comments, I want to offer such function to detect if variable is a number:

```js
function isNum (candidate) { 
  return +(candidate) === +(candidate) && //check for NaN with conversion
          candidate !== (candidate / 0) && //check for Infinity
          candidate !== '' && candidate !== null; //check for empty string and null, since +'' and +null will return 0
}

//returns false
console.log(isNum({ foo: 1 }));
console.log(isNum(''));
console.log(isNum(NaN));
console.log(isNum(undefined));
console.log(isNum(null));
console.log(isNum(Infinity));
console.log(isNum("foo1"));
console.log(isNum([1, 2, 3]));

console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------");

//returns true
console.log(isNum(9999999999));
console.log(isNum(.23));
console.log(isNum(0));
console.log(isNum(1e+30));

//will treat this also as number, since it could be easily converted  
//typeof +"112233" === "number"
console.log(isNum("112233")); 
//but still you can modify this method to use 
//typeof candidate === "string" or (candidate).constructor === String
```

Would be great to hear your comments/suggestions.

Comment: Nice. Note that the number may still be `Infinity`.

Comment: @deceze yeah, but that's another question. I think for `Infinity` we can do comparison using division by zero: `foo === (foo / 0)`, this is going to be `true` for `Infinity`.

Comment: Sure, though at that point I'm unsure why you wouldn't simply use the provided `isNan`/`isFinite` functions… :)

Comment: This does not answer the question for any types other than numbers, like strings or objects.

Comment: @deceze While we're at this, the functions you mentioned first coerce the argument to a number and *then* evaluate whether it is `NaN` or not. `Number.isNaN()` and `Number.isFinite()` are the safe counterparts (however, they were added only recently with the introduction of ES2015).

Comment: @StephanBijzitter The question itself does not formed in a good way. I see the only one question mark there "Is there a Way To compare nan with a variable?". You can convert string or object to number or NaN just adding a plus sign. Will update the answer.

Comment: if the question is unclear, you should not answer but vote to close.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Personally, I don't see the reason for voting to close it, since this question would be clarified by edits. And it has a real question, that was answered by me. You are just trying to look at the problem more globally. Anyway, thank you and have a great day.

Answer (score -2):

Ignoring your weird restriction on "no Javascript functions"…:

```
typeof num == 'number' && !isNaN(num)
```

This is the correct way to figure out if a value is a `Number` and not `NaN`. If you also want to figure out whether the number is finite (*not `Infinity`*), use an `isFinite()` instead.